# The dispatch policy prohibits event "hook_civicrm_permission" update error in 5.33

Tags: upgrade

The dispatch policy prohibits event "hook_civicrm_permission"."

```
#0 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(167): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_permission", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent))
#1 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(2016): CRM_Utils_Hook->invoke((Array:1), (Array:0), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "civicrm_permission")
#2 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Permission/Base.php(251): CRM_Utils_Hook::permission((Array:0))
#3 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Permission.php(633): CRM_Core_Permission_Base->getAllModulePermissions(TRUE)
#4 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Permission.php(577): CRM_Core_Permission::assembleBasicPermissions(FALSE, TRUE)
#5 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(74): CRM_Core_Permission::basicPermissions(FALSE, TRUE)
#6 /home/dusa/public_html/includes/module.inc(934): civicrm_permission()
#7 /home/dusa/public_html/modules/user/user.module(3124): module_invoke("civicrm", "permission")
#8 /home/dusa/public_html/profiles/panopoly/modules/contrib/features/includes/features.user.inc(87): user_permission_get_modules()
#9 /home/dusa/public_html/profiles/panopoly/modules/contrib/features/features.module(715): user_permission_features_export_render("panopoly_widgets", (Array:53), NULL, "user_permission")
#10 /home/dusa/public_html/profiles/panopoly/modules/contrib/defaultconfig/defaultconfig.features.inc(65): features_invoke("user_permission", "features_export_render", "panopoly_widgets", (Array:53), NULL)
#11 /home/dusa/public_html/profiles/panopoly/modules/contrib/features/features.module(715): defaultconfig_features_export_render("panopoly_widgets", (Array:55), NULL, "defaultconfig")
#12 /home/dusa/public_html/profiles/panopoly/modules/contrib/features/features.export.inc(1129): features_invoke("defaultconfig", "features_export_render", "panopoly_widgets", (Array:55), NULL)
#13 /home/dusa/public_html/profiles/panopoly/modules/contrib/features/features.export.inc(941): features_get_normal("defaultconfig", "panopoly_widgets", FALSE)
#14 /home/dusa/public_html/profiles/panopoly/modules/contrib/features/features.export.inc(1364): features_get_signature("normal", "panopoly_widgets", "defaultconfig", FALSE)
#15 /home/dusa/public_html/profiles/panopoly/modules/contrib/features/features.module(1200): features_get_component_states((Array:26), TRUE, FALSE)
#16 /home/dusa/public_html/profiles/panopoly/modules/contrib/features/features.module(1274): _features_restore("rebuild", (Array:0))
#17 /home/dusa/public_html/profiles/panopoly/modules/contrib/features/features.module(314): features_rebuild()
#18 /home/dusa/public_html/includes/module.inc(965): features_flush_caches()
#19 /home/dusa/public_html/includes/common.inc(7763): module_invoke_all("flush_caches")
#20 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/DrupalBase.php(288): drupal_flush_all_caches()
#21 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php(759): CRM_Utils_System_DrupalBase->flush()
#22 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php(74): CRM_Upgrade_Form::doIncrementalUpgradeFinish(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext), "5.33.alpha1", "5.32.1", "5.33.0", "/tmp/civicrm-post-upgrade887lHE")
#23 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php(202): CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))
#24 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(36): CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(TRUE)
#25 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php(90): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()
#26 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(38): CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))
#27 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(278): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()
#28 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#29 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:5))
#30 /home/dusa/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(459): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:5))
#31 /home/dusa/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("upgrade", "queue", "ajax", "runNext")
#32 /home/dusa/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#33 {main}
```

Comment: Could you try out this patch https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19345 ?

Comment: Patch worked.  Thank you.